# Table Visual Limiting Rows

Tags: powerbi

I have a list of invoices for varying days. In the same report, I want to show a table of invoices created the previous day and another table showing invoices created in the previous week.

How do I limit what data is in the tables? I can create the table fine, but it shows everything; the only way I can limit it is by page-level filters, but i want these two tables on the same page.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use visual level filters?

Comment: THanks Alexis, of course that's the answer. I'm such a newbie I knew about report-level filters and page-level filters, but did not know visual-level filters existed. What a moron.